# Xcode errors related to IPC

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, wkwebview

I have the following errors in Xcode console:

[IPC] 0x1047e7a80 - Connection::dispatchIncomingMessages: IPC throttling was triggered (has 689 pending incoming messages, will only process 600 before yielding)
[IPC] 0x1047e7a80 - Connection::dispatchIncomingMessages: first IPC message in queue is WebProcessProxy::TakeAllMessagesForPort

I am using WKWebView in my app, what does it mean?

Comment: have you got the solution for this issue?

Comment: I have upgraded Cordova IOS from 5.0.0 to 5.1.1 and now I am getting this problem. The React app now can route from the main list to a details page and then back, but after that it just refuses to react to any clicks. It seems to be busy sending some kind of IPC messages in the background

Answer (score 1):

This has just happened to me and I believe that the javascript in your WKWebView is generating messages too fast for the comms channel between the WKWebView and your Swift/Objective C code to handle.
I did think about trying to slow the message generation rate down, but on investigation all of the messages do get processed eventually and reasonably quickly, just not instantaneously, so in the end I left the error messages alone.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66286956/1122517) answer.