# Connection::dispatchIncomingMessages: IPC throttling was triggered occured when call evaluateJavascript in iOS

Tags: ios, webkit

In my app I connected my app via TCP socket (global queue with serial) and get the data from the server and send it to the webView via wkWebview.evaluateJavascript in RunLoop.main

- Socket

```
   func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didRead data: Data, withTag tag: Int) {
    delegate?.onReceive(encodedData: data)
     
    self.socket?.readData(withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
  }
```

- Subject (Combine) for receiving from the socket

```
     self.onReceivedSubject
      .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
      .sink { (_) in
         
      } receiveValue: { [weak self] (info) in
        self?.callJavascriptFunc(function: WebConstants.JSFunction.socketDataReceived,
                   param: "'\(info)'")
      }.store(in: &disposables)
```

- Call evaluateJavascript

```
   private func callJavascriptFunc(function: String, param: String) {
    let functionWithParams = WebConstants.JSFunction.javascript + "\(function)(\(param));"
     
    webView?.evaluateJavaScript(functionWithParams, completionHandler: { (result, error) in
// Do nothing..
    })
  }
```

The data from socket is little bit huge and called **evaluateJavaScript** a hundred in minutes.

Everything works fine but after few seconds, I got below errors and my app's UI is whole blocked.

***IConnection::dispatchIncomingMessages: IPC throttling was triggered (has 689 pending incoming messages, will only process 600 before yielding)***

How could I fixed this and what's the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out.

In my program, below code called in many times and seems this **evaluateJavascript** waits until its **completionHandler** arrive with blocking other process. In other words this produces lots of **messages** which can be processed than expected. Finally it blocks process.

```
    webView?.evaluateJavaScript(functionWithParams, completionHandler: { (result, error) in

})
```

So my solution is to run **Run loop** while it waits its completionHandler.

```
    webView?.evaluateJavaScript(functionWithParams, completionHandler: { (result, error) in
        isFinished = true
    })
    
    /// Prevent no to block the thread, just run once before receving the response.
    while !isFinished {
        RunLoop.current.run(mode: .default, before: Date.distantFuture)
    }
```

Comment: How does the following line of code execute if what you say is true, that it blocks while waiting?